# How to Mass Reload Bookmarks Icons?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bookmarks

Every time I resync my bookmarks they comeback to me icon-less. This also happens when I update my browser, so how could I go about mass re-loading these icons?

Browsers are Chrome and Firefox.

I use Xmarks.

Please no suggestion of "open all in new tab".

Comment: What browser, and how do you sync them?

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question but since the addon in the other answer does not exist anymore I will give a new answer.

On Firefox you can use the Checkmarks addon to refresh all bookmark icons:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkmarks-web-ext/

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox you might be able to use this extension:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/faviconreloader/?src=search

Comment: "This add-on has been removed by its author".

Comment: Doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Reason why the author removed it: [\[Support\] FavIconReloader - Mozilla Discourse](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/support-faviconreloader/6723).